How to break object reference when updating a signal's nested properties in Angular?
I have a Customer object wrapped inside a signal in Angular like this:
mCustomer: Signal<Customer> = signal(new Customer(id: 1, ...));
This signal is provided through a service which uses ngRx Signal State. and this service is injected into both Component 1 and Component 2.
In Component 1, I update the name property of the mCustomer signal directly like this (without using .set() or .update() on the signal):
mCustomer().name = "Abc";
This change is reflected in Component 2's mCustomer() signal variable. This behavior is due to object references in JavaScript. However, I want to break the object reference and follow Angular’s signal mechanism, ensuring that changes propagate only when I explicitly use .set() or .update().
My question:

How can I break the reference so that the signal updates immutably, and changes are only reflected when .set() or .update() is called?

What’s the best practice in Angular Signals for handling nested objects or properties to prevent direct mutation while maintaining immutability?


I’m looking for a way to enforce immutability and follow the signal update mechanism properly. Any suggestions or patterns to achieve this?
